# Showing map inside polygon in layout QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have **layout 1** with four different map presentations. Each of these
four has a name (ex: mapa_dv, mapa_dr, mapa_lf, mapa_rh, ...).

I have **layout 2**, where I want show "map_dv" inside an *irregular polygon* **(Add Polygon can be irregular polygon)**.

How do I draw the "map_dv" of **layout 1** within this irregular polygon of **layout 2**?

[image]

Comment: why are you talking about **two** layouts ? isn't your aim only to "frame" the map using the irregular polygon ?

Comment: @snaileater, I'm talking about two layouts because I want two different presentations for the same map in different pages. In layout 1, regular rectangular presentation (Add map). In layout 2, irregular presentation (Add polygon).

Comment: For that layout, I think the closest you can do is use regular rectangular maps for Map 1 and Map3, but rotate them. For Map 2, use the method I described below. Send Map 2 to the back, and bring Maps 1 and 3 in front of Map 2.

Answer (score 4):

there is a clipping to polygon function now: see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/38024

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

The "Map Item" in print layout can only display a *rectangular* map. Irregular and circular maps are only possible by adding elements on top of the map to cover the edges of the map. This means you can't "tesselate" or "interlock" multiple irregular maps, because the pieces that cover the edges of one map will also cover the adjacent map.

**Here's how to achieve a single irregularly shaped map:**

- Open both layouts.
- Select the "map_dv" item in **layout 1.** Copy it (ctrl-C) and paste it (ctrl-V) into **layout 2**.
- Use the "add node item" button to draw the irregular polygon on top of "map_dv." Make the fill style of the polygon "no brush." Style the border of this polygon as you want the border of your map.

  [image]
- Use the "add node item" button again to draw additional polygons that cover the area outside of the framing polygon.

  [image]
- Make the fill and border color of these polygons white. Use the "raise selected items" button to move the framing polygon to the front.

  [image]
- Select the map item and the polygon items, and group them together (use the "group items" button). This allows you to move them around in the layout as one single item.

**Other options for creating a non-rectangular map:**

- Export your maps as raster images. Use the node item in the print layout to make a polygon the shape you want your map to be. Use the raster images as the polygon fill for the node item. (At that point you might as well use an image processing software to create the final product.)
- Add a vector polygon layer to your map canvas. Draw a polygon around the area you want in your map. Use the "inverted polygon" style to cover the area outside the polygon. This method achieves basically the same results as I described in detail above, but it's done in the map canvas instead of the print layout.

Comment: Thanks @csk. I have done your steps, but isn't running for my purpose because the outside polygons cover others that I need. I was thinking call the map across the "Geometry generator". Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: I answered the question I thought you were asking, but I must not understand what you're actually asking. Can you add an illustration to your question? Just paste your map in to Paint or some similar program, and draw what you want it to look like.

Comment: I want fit different maps inside the same layout like a tetris, where every piece has a different map. For this reason I think that the best way to do is calling the map form inside the irregular polygon. (The example image is in question)

Comment: No, QGIS can't do that. The closest you could get is if you exported your maps as raster images, and used the raster images as the polygon fill for the node item in the print layout. At that point you might as well use an image processing software to create the final product.

Comment: But that would be a cool feature. You can make a feature request here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Is it possible to make the map circular (in stead of irregular or rectangular)?

Comment: Thanks @csk. It's a shame that QGIS can't do this, but I believe that will do it. I'll put this request in github !!! Thanks again !!!

Comment: @9ls1, "Add map" in layout only allow regular polygon (square or rectangular) for make the presentation of maps. Not circular. The elements you can insert don't allow show maps inside them.